# Change Armor Stands Pose with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a map on Java 1.20.1 and I'm making it have a cashier (armor stand, in a store). And I want it to move to the block to its left and then its arms up & down at different times so it looks like it's *typing* on the register, and then it goes back to its original position, with arms back to the original pose. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the pose of an armor stand using the `/data` command.
You can also use [this website](https://haselkern.com/Minecraft-ArmorStand/) to generate armor stand poses.

A typing animation would look like this (with each line being in a separate command block or delayed in some other way):

```
/data merge entity <selector> {Pose:{LeftArm:[283f,0f,0f],RightArm:[305f,0f,0f]}}
/data merge entity <selector> {Pose:{LeftArm:[305f,0f,0f],RightArm:[283f,0f,0f]}}
```

The entity can be moved by using the teleport command (which I assume you already know how to use, since it's elementary).

```
tp <selector> <desired coordinates>
```